# Como acelerar o tempo de execução do Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante no mundo da programação, eu criei um script para percorrer a tabela 1 e trazer os valores conforme estão na tabela 2 conforme os períodos nela informados.

O script funciona corretamente porem ele é bem lento na hora de execução. gostaria de uma ajuda para tentar deixar ele mais rápido.

Pesquisei sobre matrizes mas não consegui entender para poder aplicar nessa função.

```js
function teste() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Página6");
  var tabela = ss.getRange(3, 9, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  for(var l1 = 3 ; l1 <= tabela.length ; l1 ++ ){
    var tab1 = ss.getRange(l1,8).getValue();
    for( var l2 = 3 ; l2 <= tabela.length ; l2 ++ ){
      var tab2 = ss.getRange(l2,12).getValue();

      if (tab1 == tab2){

        for( var col = 13 ; col < 17 ; col ++){
             var coluna = ss.getRange(2, col).getValue();

          if( ss.getRange(l1, 9).getValue() == ss.getRange(2, col).getValue()){
               ss.getRange(l2, col).setValue(ss.getRange(l1, 10).getValue());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

[image: Imagem mostrando a tabela]

Comment: este é o site do SO em português, traduza sua pergunta